# How to pass value from custom directive to html page which is in templateUrl

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive

I have written a standard code to write the custom directive which displays the page defined in the templateUrl, and its working good with the code shown as below.

Now I want to pass variable with assigned value to that html page with this custom directive by any mechanism.

**Code snippet**

```
module FlexAttrib {
    'use strict';


    function FlexAttribDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        var directive = <ng.IDirective>{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'flexibleattributes.html',
            replace: false,
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            }
        };

        return directive;
    }
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You can use $scope variables to pass data to/from html template right?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, using scope may solve your problem and adding your desired properties like this scope: { var: '@' } and you can add the value var="value" in your directive code in HTML

Comment: Since you dont have an isolated scope on your directive, you can just access the parent scope, you just need to set the var on scope, and output it on html {{var}}

Comment: @Edrees Thanks, it worked for me but I am passing an array and able to get it as string on the next page. I want to use it as a array only as I will be passing it to ng-repeat.        Any idea, how it can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your valuable suggestions it helped. Here is the final working solution for my above asked question.

**Code Snippet:**

**1. Directive Code**

```
module FlexAttrib {
    'use strict';

    function FlexAttribDirective(): ng.IDirective {
        var directive = <ng.IDirective>{
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: './app/shared/templates/flexibleattributes.html',
            replace: false,
            scope : {
                flexibleattributes: '=',
            },
        };

        return directive;
    }

}
```

**2. syntax to pass variable/data as a directive attribute (written in HTML file where directive is to be called)**

```
<dir-flex-attrib flexibleattributes="ElementFlexibleAttributes"></dir-flex-attrib>
```

**Note:**  ElementFlexibleAttributes is the name of array containing data which I am passing through directive attribute.

Thanks.